# fitNaiveBayes vs NaiveBayes.fit

Tags: matlab

When I want to use `fitNaiveBayes`  I get this error:

```
Undefined function 'fitNaiveBayes' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

I also tried this:

```
which fitNaiveBayes

'fitNaiveBayes' not found.
```

but I can use `NaiveBayes.fit`

My question is: Is there any difference between them?

---

My matlab version is R2011b(7.13.0.564)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a more recent function.  The online help for [NaiveBayes.fit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/naivebayes.fit.html) says:

> Note:   fit will be removed in a future release. Use fitNaiveBayes
>   instead.

The inputs and options look to me to be identical.